# Why fork bomb did not crash android?

Tags: android, linux, shell, su

This is the simplest fork bomb

```
:() { :|: & }; :
```

I executed it on many linux distros and all of them crashed.

But when I executed this in an android terminal there was no effect even after granting **Super user** permissions.

Any Explanations why it did not crash the android system?

Comment: It does work in Android 10 and Termux

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a word: `ulimit`.  the linux kernel allows a limit on the number of child processes, this can be tweaked using the ulimit() system call or the ulimit shell builtin.

eg:

```
ulimit -u 5
```