# How to crash Android's linux kernel?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, crash

I'm attempting to crash a kernel.

I've been using `echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger`, but I was wondering if there is a way for users to "naturally" crash a kernel.

Answer (score 0):

A [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) is a sure way to crash a kernel. Apparently this was fixed on Android by setting a max number of child processes, [but that limit can be removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466905/why-fork-bomb-did-not-crash-android).